# Replacing empty values with nulls in JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string:

`var str = "[,,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6]";`

I want to replace all "empty" values with nulls. In other words, I want this result:

`"[null,null,null,1,2,null,null,3,4,null,null,null,null,null,5,6]"`

This *almost* works, but it misses the first empty value:

```
var str = "[,,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6]";
str.split(',').map(function(x) { return x ? x : 'null' }).join(',')
// Gives [,null,null,1,2,null,null,3,4,null,null,null,null,null,5,6]
```

Likewise, I noticed if I have trailing empty values, it misses the last one there too:

```
var str = "[,,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6,,]";
str.split(',').map(function(x) { return x ? x : 'null' }).join(',')
// Gives [,null,null,1,2,null,null,3,4,null,null,null,null,null,5,6,null,]
```

Any ideas how I can make sure that first and last empty values are also replaced?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the [ ] and test

Comment: everything is working as expected you have indeed removed all empty values if you just use 
str.split(',').map(function(x) { return x ? x : 'null' })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned - the [ and ] are altering your return - this removes them and using the same function as your existing function - but on the shortened string  and returns the correct value.

```js
var str = "[,,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6]";
let newStr = str.substring(1,str.length-1).split(',').map(function(x) { return x ? x : 'null' }).join(',')

console.log(newStr);
// Gives [null,null,null,1,2,null,null,3,4,null,null,null,null,null,5,6]


var str = "[,,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6,,]";

newStr = str.substring(1,str.length-1).split(',').map(function(x) { return x ? x : 'null' }).join(',');
console.log(newStr);
// Gives null,null,null,1,2,null,null,3,4,null,null,null,null,null,5,6,null,null
```

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense. Doh! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this is going to work:

```js
  var str = "[,,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6]";
  var result = '[' + str.replace(/^\[|\]$/g, '').split(/[,]/).map(function(x) { return x ? x : 'null' }).join(',') + ']';
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The secret is that your brackets are getting combined with your commas / numbers at the start and end of the string when it is split. In order to resolve this, you need to remove the brackets **before** splitting.

This can be done with **[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** on `/[\][]/g`:

```js
var str = "[,,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6,]";
console.log(
  str.replace(/[\][]/g, '').split(',').map(function(x) {
    return x ? x : 'null'
  }).join(',')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "[,,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6]";
var a = `[${str.slice(1, -1).split(",").map(n => n || "null")}]`
  
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have removed all the empty values. "[" and "]" are not nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.repEmptyWithNull = 
function() {return this
  .replace(/,,/g, ',null,')
  .replace(/,,/g, ',null,')
  .replace('[,', '[null,')
  .replace(',]', ',null]')
}

console.log ("[,,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6,]".repEmptyWithNull())
console.log ("[,,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6]".repEmptyWithNull())
console.log ("[,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6,,]".repEmptyWithNull())
console.log ("[,1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6]".repEmptyWithNull())
console.log ("[1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6,]".repEmptyWithNull())
console.log ("[1,2,,,3,4,,,,,,5,6]".repEmptyWithNull())
```